# How to assign an output with combinational logic on a parametric design

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog

I want to implement a multiplexer that given a control signal (addr_i) puts in to the output(data_o) the content of a register(slv_reg[i]). Where "i" is a value from 0 to the module parameter TOTAL_REGS.
Can I assign the slv_reg in a for loop without generating a latch?

I have written a couple of simple examples. But even if my logic covers all the possible conditions if an else is missing it generates a latch. When doing it manually, I can write the else and get rid of the problem, but when using a loop, I don't know how to do it.

```
module why_latch_1 #                                                 
    (                                                                
        // Width of data bus                                         
        parameter integer DATA_WIDTH    = 32,                        
        // Number of registers                                       
        parameter integer TOTAL_REGS = 3                             
    )                                                                
    (                                                                
     input wire clk_i,                                               
     input wire rstn_i,                                              
     input wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] addr_i,                             
     output wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_o                             
    );                                                               
    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] slv_reg [0:TOTAL_REGS-1];                   
    reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] reg_data_out;                               
    assign data_o = reg_data_out;                                    

    integer i;                                                       

    always @(posedge clk_i)                                          
        if (~rstn_i) begin                                           
            for (i=0; i<TOTAL_REGS; i=i+1) begin                     
                slv_reg[i]<={DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};                      
            end                                                      
        end                                                          

    always_comb                                                      
    begin : decode                                                   
    //check if the address is out of the range of R registers        
        if (addr_i>0 && addr_i <= TOTAL_REGS) begin                  
            //this is a latch                                        
            integer i;                                               
            for(i=0;i<TOTAL_REGS;i++)begin                           
                if(addr_i==i) begin                                  
                    reg_data_out =slv_reg[i];                        
                end                                                  
            end                                                      
        end else                                                     
            reg_data_out ={DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};                        
    end                                                              
    endmodule
```

```
module why_latch_2 #                                      
(                                                         
    // Width of data bus                                  
    parameter integer DATA_WIDTH    = 32,                 
    // Number of registers                                
    parameter integer TOTAL_REGS = 3                      
)                                                         
(                                                         
 input wire clk_i,                                        
 input wire rstn_i,                                       
 input wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] addr_i,                      
 output wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_o                      
);                                                        
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] slv_reg [0:TOTAL_REGS-1];            
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] reg_data_out;                        
assign data_o = reg_data_out;                             

integer i;                                                

always @(posedge clk_i)                                   
    if (~rstn_i) begin                                    
        for (i=0; i<TOTAL_REGS; i=i+1) begin              
            slv_reg[i]<={DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};               
        end                                               
    end                                                   

always_comb                                               
begin : decode                                            
//check if the address is out of the range of R registers 
    if (addr_i>0 && addr_i <= TOTAL_REGS) begin           
        //this is NOT a latch                             
        if(addr_i==0)                                     
            reg_data_out =slv_reg[0];                     
        else                                              
            if(addr_i==1)                                 
                reg_data_out =slv_reg[1];                 
            else                                          
                reg_data_out =slv_reg[2];                 
    end else                                              
        reg_data_out ={DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};                 
end                                                       
endmodule
```

By using spyglass as a linting tool, I get the following reports:

For module why_latch_2. Everything is fine, as I was expecting.

```
############### BuiltIn -> RuleGroup=Design Read ###############                
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ID       Rule                    Alias                   Severity    File                                                                                  Line    Wt    Message
======================================================================================
[1]      DetectTopDesignUnits    DetectTopDesignUnits    Info        ./why_latch_2.sv                                                                      1       2     Module why_latch_2 is a top level desi
gn unit
[0]      ElabSummary             ElabSummary             Info        ./why_latch_2/why_latch_2/lint/lint_rtl/spyglass_reports/SpyGlass/elab_summary.rpt    0       2     Please refer file './why_latch_2/why_l
atch_2/lint/lint_rtl/spyglass_reports/SpyGlass/elab_summary.rpt' for elab summary report
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

For why_latch_1:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++         
MORESIMPLE REPORT:                                                              


############### BuiltIn -> RuleGroup=Design Read ###############                
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ID       Rule                    Alias                   Severity            File                                                                                  Line    Wt      Message
======================================================================================
[1]      DetectTopDesignUnits    DetectTopDesignUnits    Info                ./why_latch_1.sv                                                                      1       2       Module why_latch_1 is a top 
level design unit
[4]      SYNTH_12608                                     SynthesisWarning    ./why_latch_1.sv                                                                      27      1000    why_latch_1 -> The logic of 
the always block mismatches with the type of Always Block(which should be "always_latch (Latch)") due to latch instance \reg_data_out_reg[0]
[0]      ElabSummary             ElabSummary             Info                ./why_latch_1/why_latch_1/lint/lint_rtl/spyglass_reports/SpyGlass/elab_summary.rpt    0       2       Please refer file './why_lat
ch_1/why_latch_1/lint/lint_rtl/spyglass_reports/SpyGlass/elab_summary.rpt' for elab summary report
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


############### Non-BuiltIn -> Goal=lint/lint_rtl ###############               
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ID       Rule          Alias                 Severity    File                Line    Wt    Message
======================================================================================
[7]      InferLatch    (OpenMORE 5.5.2.1)    Error       ./why_latch_1.sv    40      5     Latch inferred for signal 'reg_data_out[31:0]' in module 'why_latch_1'
[2]      W415a                               Warning     ./why_latch_1.sv    35      5     Signal reg_data_out is being assigned multiple times ( assignment within same for-loop ) in same always block [Hiera
rchy: ':why_latch_1']
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should generate a latch in your case. You do not cover all possible cases here.

```
       for(i=0;i<TOTAL_REGS;i++)begin                           
            if(addr_i==i) begin                                  
                reg_data_out =slv_reg[i];                        
            end                                                  
        end
```

try this instead. Move the default case upfront:

```
begin : decode                                                   
//check if the address is out of the range of R registers        

   reg_data_out ='0;    // do default assignment before the rest                     

   if (addr_i>0 && addr_i <= TOTAL_REGS) begin                  
        //this is a latch                                        
        integer i;                                               
        for(i=0;i<TOTAL_REGS;i++)begin                           
            if(addr_i==i) begin                                  
                reg_data_out =slv_reg[i];                        
            end                                                  
        end                                                      
   end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution gets rid of the latch, but the linting tools throw a  warning about multiple assignments.

Wouldn't be better to do something like this?
```
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] slv_reg[0:TOTAL_REGS-1];

always @(posedge clk_i) begin
    if (~rstn_i) begin
        for (integer i=0; i<TOTAL_REGS; i=i+1) begin
            slv_reg[i]<=0;
        end
    end
end

assign data_o = (addr_i > 0 && addr_i < TOTAL_REGS)? slv_reg[addr_i]: 0;
```

I have tried you solution and the one in this comment and vivado maps it to different hardware but functionally shall be the same.

Comment: linting tools should not complain about multiple assignments in the same always block. Only if you assign the same signal in separate blocks they should complain. If they do, talk to the linting tool vendor. This is a common verilog programming style.